# FileTable and entity framework code first?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, code-first, filetable

I have a MVC project and I want to use SQL `FileTable` for storing photos and attachments.
But it seems to me that Entity Framework code first does not support `FileTable`.

All I could think of was to use script in Up method of migration to alter database and create `FileTable`.

Is there any better approach?

Comment: What's the actual question here?

Comment: The better approach is to use SQL table to store the BLOB URL and use BLOB storage to store the actual file. You will get the benefit of access policies and more. If you use SQL for files your Db will degrade with time. SQL is not good for storing Binary Large Objects ( BLObs )